# How to dynamically alter inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I would like to dynamically specify the parent class for a class in Ruby.  Consider this code:

```
class Agent
  def self.hook_up(calling_class, desired_parent_class)
    # Do some magic here
  end
end

class Parent
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

class Child
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end

  Agent.hook_up(self, Parent)
end

Child.new.bar
```

Neither the `Parent` nor the `Child` class definition specifies a parent class, so they both inherit from Object.  My first question is: what would I need to do in `Agent.hook_up` in order to make `Parent` the superclass of `Child` (so for example `Child` objects can inherit the 'bar' method).

My second question is: do I *need* to pass the first argument to `Agent.hook_up`, or is there some way the `hook_up` method can programmatically determine the class from which it was called?

Comment: Um, if you're dynamically setting or changing the parent of a class then it's a reasonable assertion that your object model doesn't reflect a true *is-a* relationship. A more suitable solution is probably composition.

Comment: You should make clear if this is a thought exercise, or why you'd want to use that in practice. Dynamic reflective languages do not mean it's clean to dynamically change inheritance.
With great (expressive) power, comes great responsibility :)

Comment: @cletus I'm not a big fan of inheritance in general but for the problem I'm currently looking at, inheritance and the is-a relationship perfectly describe the relationship.  The only problem is that an object won't know what it 'is' until run time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Joshua has already given you a great list of alternatives, but to answer your question: You can't change the superclass of a class after the class has been created in ruby. That's simply not possible.

Comment: @Borromakot status of challenge?

Comment: @Borromakot, unless you override their memory locations :)

Answer (score 25):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
Child = Class.new Parent do
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end

Child.ancestors   # => [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel]
Child.new.bar     # => "bar"
Child.new.foo     # => "foo"
```

Since parent is an argument to Class.new, you can swap it out with other classes.

I've used this technique before when writing certain kinds of tests. But I have difficulty thinking of many good excuses to do such a thing.

---

I suspect what you really want is a module.

```
class Agent
  def self.hook_up(calling_class, desired_parent_class)
    calling_class.send :include , desired_parent_class
  end
end

module Parent
  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

class Child
  def foo
    "foo"
  end

  Agent.hook_up(self, Parent)
end

Child.ancestors   # => [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel]
Child.new.bar     # => "bar"
Child.new.foo     # => "foo"
```

---

Though, of course, there is no need for the Agent at all

```
module Parent
  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

class Child
  def foo
    "foo"
  end

  include Parent
end

Child.ancestors   # => [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel]
Child.new.bar     # => "bar"
Child.new.foo     # => "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua.  Since it appears that I can't change the inheritance chain at runtime, I'll probably end up using some variation of your first option in my solution.  I appreciate the time you put into responding.

Comment: Another thing you can look at, if this is _really_ what you want to do, is change_class written by Ryan Davis. Here is the video where he introduces the code at 5:00 http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/evil-code.html

Here is the project's home page. http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/change_class/ 

Note the disclaimer "Yes, it is dangerous... don’t come crying to me if your computer ignites."

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 1.9 only: (1.8 is similar, but use RCLASS(self)->super instead)

```
require 'inline'
class Class
    inline do |builder|

        builder.c %{            
            VALUE set_super(VALUE sup) {
                RCLASS(self)->ptr->super = sup;
                return sup;
            }
        }

        builder.c %{
            VALUE get_super() {
                return RCLASS(self)->ptr->super;
            }
        }

    end


J = Class.new
J.set_super(Class.new)
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out already, you should probably look into modules or dynamically create classes. However, you can use [evil-ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/evil) to change the superclass. There even is a [fork for Ruby 1.9](http://code.google.com/p/evil-ruby/) available. This does only work for MRI. Should be easy to build on Rubinius (clearing methods caches would be the main issue), no clue about JRuby. Here is the code:

```
require 'evil'

class Agent
  def self.hook_up(calling_class, desired_parent_class)
    calling_class.superclass = desired_parent_class
  end
end

class Parent
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

class Child
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end

  Agent.hook_up(self, Parent)
end

Child.new.bar
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the use of 'evil' would probably be frowned upon in production code:-)  Dynamically creating a class is probably the solution I'll end up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old and already has some good answers. However I still miss a certain solution.

If your intention is not to dynamically assign the superclass, but rather create a hook to execute some code on inheritance ([XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). There is a build-in way to do this.

> #### inherited(subclass)
>
> Callback invoked whenever a subclass of the current class is created.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> class Foo
>   def self.inherited(subclass)
>     puts "New subclass: #{subclass}"
>   end
> end
>
> class Bar < Foo
> end
>
> class Baz < Bar
> end
> ```
>
> *produces:*
>
> ```
> New subclass: Bar
> New subclass: Baz
> ```

See: [`Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Class.html#method-i-inherited)

If your intention is to dynamically create classes, I'd recommend looking at [the answer of Joshua Cheek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127137/3982562).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [SimpleDelegator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) class (in the [delegate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html) library) may help, provided that it's sufficient that the object *quack like* the base class, rather than actually *be an instance of* the base class.

```
require 'delegate'

class Agent < SimpleDelegator
  def baz
    puts "baz"
  end
end

class BarParent
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

class FooParent
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end

agent = Agent.new(FooParent.new)
agent.baz    # => baz
agent.foo    # => foo
agent.__setobj__(BarParent.new)
agent.baz    # => baz
agent.bar    # => bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```
  class MyClass < inherit_orm("Adapter")
  end
```

And the class selector:

```
  def inherit_orm(model="Activity", orm=nil)
    orm = Config.orm || orm
    require "orm/#{orm.to_s}"
    "ORM::#{orm.to_s.classify}::#{model}".constantize
  end
```

So, when instance `MyClass` it will be inherit from a dynamic class depending of `orm` and `model`.
Be sure to define both in a module. It work fine in [public_activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) gem ( [selector example](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity/blob/master/lib/public_activity.rb#L64) ).

I hope to help.. Bye!