# Ruby How to inherit from object given in constructor

Tags: ruby, dynamic-typing

I'm new in dynamic typed programming languages, and I have problem with inheritance.
In my case I had followed Ruby class:

```
class Vertex
  def initialize(given_object, *edges)
    @o = given_object
    @e = edges
  end
end
```

And I need to extend Vertex class for object class,

```
class Vertex < given_object
```

So I need to extends my object from object that is given in constructor

I know that is basic knowledge but as I mentioned earlier I'm totally new in dynamic typed languages.

@edited:
Ok I understand, so lets consider this example:

```
class TestClass
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
    TestClass < object.class
  end
end

#now In code I want to run each method on TestClass because it should inherit from Array
v = TestClass.new([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])    
v.each { |number| print number}
```

but I got interpreter error

```
 `<top (required)>': undefined method `each' for #<TestClass:0x00000001275960 @object=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: It is not `def Vertex`, rather `class Vertex`.

Comment: Mazeryt, re your edit.  You have not defined the method `each` for `TestClass` and `each` is not defined for any of its ancestors: `TestClass.ancestors
=> [TestClass, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]`.   Hence, the undefined error exception.  You define `TestClass` with the `class` keyword.  `TestClass < object.class` is here `TestClass < Array`, which tells you whether `TestClass` is a subclass of `Array`; it does not change the parentage of `TestClass`.  Here it returns `nil`. See [Module#<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-3C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wish to use Decorator pattern, when all  methods are proxied to given model:

```
class TestClass
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    @object.send(method, *args, &block)
  end
end

v = TestClass.new([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])    
v.each { |number| print number}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't alter an object's superclass at runtime.

See [How to dynamically alter inheritance in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127069/how-to-dynamically-alter-inheritance-in-ruby) for some alternate ideas that may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `def` keyword is used for methods, not classes. Try using `class vertex` and see if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks I edited my question, can You look on edited?

Comment: The `def` keyword is used for methods, not functions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Woops, you are right. Been doing too much functional programming lately :)